# Updated rack and now getting 502 errors from CLI

Tags: convox

We just updated our rack to the latest version, as we'd been having deployment issues all week with some instances updating and others not.

Following the update, we now have a red "?" next to our rack in the console, and I get nothing but 502 errors in the CLI.

Any ideas on how to fix this?